# How to create variables accessible with Intellisense in C#

Tags: c#

I am starting to work with C# and am still learning the basics.
I've got a few different classes:

```
public class CompanyA{}
public class CompanyB{}
...
```

I need to define Adult, Child and Infant ages for each company in such a way that I could then access those "int" values with Intellisense, and where I can initialize the 'maxAge' and 'minAge' for each of them. I believe it would be something along the lines of:

```
CompanyA.Adult.minAge
CompanyB.Infant.maxAge
```

Could you please provide an example of how I can achieve this? I need to create other similar structures, so having a working example would help me a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the attempts you've made to this point.

Comment: I've been for a few hours. But I don't have much experience with this, so I'm researching and trying to find similar examples, but I cannot fully understand it just yet. I am not sure if I need to start creating classes inside, like one extra class for Ages, and then how I could assign values to each Adult,Child,Infant inside the Company class... My syntax doesn't seem correct

Answer (score 1):

First define your classes, then you can access them from intellisense.

```
public class CompanyA
{
    public Adult Adult { get; set; }
    public Infant Infant { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyB
{
    public Adult Adult { get; set; }
    public Infant Infant { get; set; }
}

public class Adult 
{
    public int MaxAge { get; set; }
    public int MinAge { get; set; }
}

public class Infant
{
    public int MaxAge { get; set; }
    public int MinAge { get; set; }
}
```

Now you will be able to access them like this:

```
CompanyA.Adult.MinAge
CompanyB.Infant.MaxAge
```

Lots of luck on your career.

Edit:

As Jay suggested in the comments, you should learn how Access Modifiers work. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) is a guide to that.

Comment: Should also show how protected and internal work

Comment: And if I am inside CompanyA class, with the Adult object for example. How could I assign it a value from there, as that would be a constant for that company... :S

Comment: This is not helpful.  Easy to find out, try to run this code yourself.  Focus on the distinction between types and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @agDev for the example above to point me in the right direction. At the end, I managed to access them with the following code:

```
public class Ages 
{
    public int MaxAge { get; set; }
    public int MinAge { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyA
{
    public Ages Adult = new Ages { MinAge = 14, MaxAge = 55 };
    public Ages Infant = new Ages { MinAge = 0, MaxAge = 4 };
}

public class CompanyB
{
    public Ages Adult = new Ages { MinAge = 18, MaxAge = 60 };
    public Ages Infant = new Ages { MinAge = 0, MaxAge = 2 };
}
```